# cannot use err (type error) as type goreq.Error in return argument

Tags: go

I am trying to return two values (result and error) from a method but I get this

```
cannot use err (type error) as type goreq.Error in return argument
```

my code

```
package components

import (
    goreq "github.com/franela/goreq"
    "time"
)

var UserAgent string = "..."

func Get(url string) (*goreq.Response, goreq.Error) {
    goreq.SetConnectTimeout(15 * time.Second)
    res, err := goreq.Request{
        Uri: url,
        UserAgent: UserAgent,
        Timeout: 5 * time.Second,
    }.Do()

    return res, err
}
```

Comment: On a side note, you should never return specific error types, only the error interface (for precisely this reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Do()` [returns type error, not `goreq.Error`](https://github.com/franela/goreq/blob/00f9aa6e4d9101db444f5d4232ee969645f91323/goreq.go#L243). Change your second return type to `error` instead of `goreq.Error`.